# Is it possible to install into Program Files with limited privileges?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, uac, privileges

I have an application that will be deployed as MSI package (authored in WiX).

I am deciding whether to specify `elevated` or `limited` privileges as required for the installer.

The application does not include anything requiring elevated privileges besides the default install location, which is under Program Files.

Now the problem:

- If I specify **elevated privileges**, then the user is prompted by UAC for administrator password during the installation. This is not required and prevents non-admin users from installing.
- If I specify **limited privileges**, then the user is presented with a dialog to select install location with `Program Files` being default. In case they do not change the install location (95 % of end users probably won't), then the installer will fail with a message that they should contact the Administrator or run the application as administrator. If they launch the installer as Administrator then they can install into Program Files without problem - but most of the users won't probably know how to launch an installer as administrator.

I can potentially set the default install location to e.g. C:\Company name\Program\, but this seems nonstandard to me and majority of users will not probably like this (they are probably used to installing into Program Files).

**How do you solve this problem with installing applications under limited user accounts?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alternate location you propose, directly off of the C Drive, is likely to also require elevated privileges. Before Windows 7, I would suggest using an early custom action to change your default location for limited installations. Condition it off of the `Privileged` (or possibly `AdminUser`) property, verify whether you need to set `MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION` for your case, and use something like `[LocalAppDataFolder]Company\Product`. Unfortunately this approach will result in a package that is difficult to install for all users as you must pre-elevate, and in the limited case they could still select a target location that requires elevation. They must pre-elevate because the package must be marked to not elevate.

If you can target solely Windows 7 and later, you can conditionally set `MSIINSTALLPERUSER` to override the install location and the elevation requirement, and instead install per-user. In this scenario, the user could be asked whether to install for all users (requires elevation) or just for himself. The package can be marked for elevation, and setting `MSIINSTALLPERUSER` will override that and skip the UAC prompt.

Comment: No, the alternate location does not require elevated privileges. I am currently installing by default into C:\Company name\Product and the MSI installer is built with limited privileges and no UAC comes up, nor any error dialog.

Comment: That sounds like a custom environment then, but that's fine if you know it'll be in place anywhere your product is installed. The rest of the answer applies; merely ignore the limited privilege location suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably more important that your software runs with normal user privileges - which I see you've mentioned isn't an issue.

There's nothing wrong in asking for admin rights to install something.

Either, the user will have the details themselves as they are running a limited account for safety reasons or the software will be installed by their company's IT department anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Run command prompt(cmd) as administrator.

Then use msiexec command to execute msi file.

Comment: I can not ask the end user to do this

Comment: u can ask user to do this...as for installing any s/w one should have admin privileges. So thers nothing wrong in asking him to do so. Or you can aks user to login with admin credentials and then install s/w